# How do I fetch values from database and display them in select option in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have created below code to do calculation on the data fetched from database. Steps:

Fetch the value that will be used by javascript to do calculation from database and display using `'u" value="'`
Do calculation using javascript using the values fetched. `'u'`

All what i require is to fetch those values and use it to calculate in JavaScript but nothing happens.

Below code fetches the data and values

```
    <select name="urgency" id="urgency"  class="form-control"  onchange="caltotal()">
    <?php
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT idurgency,amount_added,value,hours_day FROM cww_avid_urgency");

    foreach ($query as $key => $row) {
    if ($row['idurgency'] == $post['urgency']) {
    echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $row['idurgency'] . 'u" value="' . $row['idurgency'] . '"  title="' . $row['amount_added'] . '">' . $row['value'] . $row['hours_day'] . '</option>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $row['idurgency'] . 'u" value="' . $row['idurgency'] . '"  title="' . $row['amount_added'] . '">' . $row['value'] . $row['hours_day'] . '</option>';
    }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Below is the input type to display the values after the calculation

```
            <input type="text" name="cpp" id="cpp" value="10.95" class="form-control" maxlength="14" readonly>
            <b>Currency Code</b>
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input name="tamount" type="text" id="tamount" value="10.95" class="form-control" readonly>
            <b>Currency Code</b> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <span class="tamount"></span>
     </div>
```

Below is the script to do calculations and to make changes onselect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function caltotal() {
      var x = document.getElementById("urgency").value;
       if (document.getElementById("urgency").value == 'u') {
  var  u = 10.95;
  document.getElementById("cpg").value =  +u;
  document.getElementById("ta").value =  +u;
  document.getElementById("np").value =  +u;
  } else if (document.getElementById("urgency").value == 'u') {
  var  u = 11.95;
  document.getElementById("cpg").value =  +u;
  document.getElementById("ta").value =  +u;
  document.getElementById("np").value =  +u;
  } else if (document.getElementById("urgency").value == 'u') {
  var  u = 12.95;
  document.getElementById("cpg").value =  +u;
  document.getElementById("ta").value =  +u;
  document.getElementById("np").value =  +u;
  } 
   </script>
```

The results that I expecting that when select urgency is selected the affects the display likewise the rest of selects.

Comment: https://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/chained-ajax-selects-jquery

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here that are not right with your code.

1. The if in your foreach loop prints the same result regardless of the
   $row['idurgency'] making it redundant.
2. Option tags do not need an id attribute, and may even be causing the
   problem. The id attribute should be unique and only assigned once per page.
3. Then some of your javascript is redundant as well.

> ```
> function caltotal() {
>     var urgency = document.getElementById("urgency").value;
>     var amount;
>     if (urgency == 'u') {
>         amount = 10.95;
>     } else if (urgency == '?') {
>         amount = 11.95;
>     } else if (urgency == '??') {
>         amount = 12.95;
>     }
>
>     document.getElementById("cpg").value += amount;
>     document.getElementById("ta").value += amount;
>     document.getElementById("np").value += amount;
> }
> ```

Just make sure you have only one element on the page that has one of the three names, cpg, ta, np.

I would advise you use more descriptive names for your variables it will help you in the long run.

Comment: I got some error  ```undefined```.  ```U``` Its not fetching the value from database